Why is the form of the ladder operators for the QHO what it is?
I'm trying to deepen my understanding of the ladder operators for the quantum harmonic oscillator now that I'm further along in my physics degree, and I can't seem to find anything on why they take the forms they do. I fully understand the formalism from a linear algebra perspective, but I don't see how, starting from $$\hat{N}|n\rangle = \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}|n\rangle = n |n \rangle$$ and progressing to $$\hat{a}^\dagger |n \rangle = \sqrt{n + 1} |n +1\rangle; \ \hat{a}|n\rangle = \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle,$$ we somehow arrive at $$\hat{x} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} (\hat{a}^\dagger + \hat{a});\ \hat{p} = i\sqrt{\frac{\hbar m \omega}{2}}(\hat{a}^\dagger - \hat{a}).$$
As a footnote, I'm comfortable with linear algebra, group theory, and abstract algebra, but I haven't looked specifically at Lie algebras yet.

Isn't it --usually-- the other way around? I.e. you start from the definition in terms of $X$ and $P$, and then derive properties of the operators?!

As others have said, you normally start with position and momentum operators, then define the creation and annihilation operators (Griffifths has a nice intuitive justification for this in terms of factoring the Hamiltonian), then deriving the number operator. But, you could theoretically start with the commutation relations $[a, a^\dagger] = 1$, then look for s linear combinations $x$ and $p$ with the right dimensions for $x$ to be position and $p$ momentum such that $[x, p]=i\hbar$. I'm not sure what that would prove, but mathematically you could do this.

The simplest starting point is the classical harmonic oscillator with Hamiltonian
$$
H=\frac{1}{2m}p^2 +\frac{1}{2}kx^2\, .
$$
The resulting equations of motions
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\begin{array}{c} 
x\\ p\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1/m\\
-k&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\ p\end{array}\right)
$$
is a set of coupled linear equations.  To decouple these equation you introduce the variables
$$
\alpha= x-im\omega p\, ,\qquad 
\alpha^*=x+im\omega p
$$
with $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$, so the equations of motion are now $\dot\alpha=i\omega \alpha$ and likewise for $\alpha^*$.
The equations of motions involve the Poisson brackets
$$
\dot{\alpha}=\{\alpha,H\}\, .
$$
You can see the strong similarity with the quantum harmonic oscillator and the commutator with the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian.
In the quantum case, the operators $\hat a^\dagger$ and $\hat a$ have “normalization” factors adjusted so $\hat a^\dagger\hat a+\frac12$ is $\hat H/\hbar\omega$.
Of course the mathematical answer starts with Lie algebras, where it is natural given $\hat x,\hat p$ and $\hat H$ to search for ladder operators $\hat a,\hat a^\dagger$ that will return a multiple of themselves under commutation with $\hat H$, just like one does with the introduction of $\hat L_\pm$ and $\hat L_z$ for angular momentum.

Thank you! This is a perfect intuition, and I really appreciated that you suggested further math to read up on. Amazing answer  :)


but I don't see how, starting from...

Well, that actually is not what we do. In QHO, usually we start with a Hamiltonian operator of an Harmonic Oscillator, entirely constructed based on the Principle of Correspondence, and then we build up the Ladder and Number operators from position and momentum. Look that later in physics we learn that the EM field has a similar Hamiltonian of a QHO, but it is in fact a very different object. In Quantum Optics we start through ladder and number operators, and we not arrive at position and momentum operators.

I see. When you say "then we build up the ladder and number operators from position and momentum", how do we do that? How do we get $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}$ from $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$? It just seems like every source just states the answer instead of how they got there

@AryanMP It is an "educational guess". Note that the definition of $a$ (and thus $a^\dagger$) in the context of the QHO Hamiltonian resembles the concept of "completing the square". IIRC, there are some questions here on PSE regarding the motivation of that definition already...
